# Why is this string comparison in Jest's expect not failing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I am taking my first steps with `ReactJS` and `Jest`.

The expect below passes, even though it shouldn't. See how the property is printing:

```
console.log(searchBox.props.url_variation); 
// prints: curation/get_site_variations/
```

So why is the expect not failing?

```
jest.dontMock('../databank_web/static/js/curation_tools/SearchBox.js');

describe('SearchBox', function () {
    it('loads results after click', function () {
        var React = require('react/addons');
        var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
        var SearchBox = require('../databank_web/static/js/curation_tools/SearchBox.js');

        // Render the form?
        var searchBox = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<SearchBox
            url_variation="curation/get_site_variations/"
            url_golden="curation/golden_record/"/>);


        console.log(searchBox.props.url_variation); // prints: curation/get_site_variations/

        expect(searchBox.props.url_variation === "fail");
// Why is this passing? fail is not equal to 'curation/get_site_variations/'

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your expect to the following:

```
expect(searchBox.props.url_variation).toEqual("fail")
```

This will cause the test to fail.  The reason it is passing is that `expect(false)` does not cause a test to fail.  I believe this behavior is actually inherited from Jasmine where expectations alone just act as values.  The chained matchers are what causes the test to pass or fail.